# delete items from mysql table with out knowing id

Tags: mysql

For my project i am creating a sales order page which have order items on the grid. So when user add new items and hit save then the ID of the selected item will save on DB.

Everything works well except deleted items, Because we are not passing any deleted item on save.

Ex.

```
recordId, product_id, is_deleted
```

Currently i am looping through the items and checking If its exists on DB, Pseudo code

```
IF( ITEM_EXISTS  ){

 //update

}
else{

 //Insert 

}
```

But it will not cover any deleted items on the page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `not in` in mysql

like this

```
 UPDATE table_name 
    SET table_name.is_deleted = true 
    where 
    table_name.recordId not in ( current ids ) 
    and 
    parent_id = your_master_table_id
```

here `current_id` is coming from your page and it should be comma separated.`Parent_Id` is your sales_order table primary key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your recordId,primary key.